# Why can’t I connect to my Dell PowerConnect 2824 switch?

Tags: networking, switch

I am new to home-labbing and have my Xfinity modem outputting into port 1 of the Dell PowerConnect 2824 switch.

I have a desktop and 2 servers hooked up to it and they are getting internet without any configuration. But I’m unable to log into the switch at all.

I can log into the Xfinity modem no problem from all machines. What am I doing wrong? How can I properly connect to the Dell PowerConnect 2824 switch?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Thanks, @Giacomo1968. I didn't actually even open the page, as the Google search first hit was a Dell page stating these are unmanaged. Deleted the comment.

Comment: The instructions for starting to use the device, including the how-to-connect are in the [Getting Started guide](https://downloads.dell.com/manuals/all-products/esuprt_ser_stor_net/esuprt_networking/esuprt_net_fxd_prt_swtchs/powerconnect-2824_setup%20guide_en-us.pdf) and [User Guide](https://downloads.dell.com/manuals/all-products/esuprt_ser_stor_net/esuprt_networking/esuprt_net_fxd_prt_swtchs/powerconnect-2824_user%27s%20guide_en-us.pdf) (direct PDF downloads from Dell site).

Comment: @Peregrino69 I just briefly looked through the linked PDFs and you should post the details as a full answer. The web interface should be on `192.168.2.1` and the way to switch between managed/unmanaged is to just push a button. More details on page 13 of [this PDF](https://downloads.dell.com/manuals/all-products/esuprt_ser_stor_net/esuprt_networking/esuprt_net_fxd_prt_swtchs/powerconnect-2824_setup%20guide_en-us.pdf). “The PowerConnect 2808/16/24/48 has a Mode push button on the front panel. The Mode button changes between Managed and Unmanaged modes, or changes from Secure to Managed modes.”

Comment: @Peregrino69 Just [posted a full answer](https://superuser.com/a/1772918/167207) based on the details provided in those PDFs you found. Thanks for finding them!

Comment: Thanks @Giacomo1968 for going through the trouble :-)

Comment: @Peregrino69  yeah I've ran through those steps many times without success. I just said screw it and bought a new switch lol

Answer (score 0):

### To use the Dell PowerConnect 2824 switch in managed mode you need to explicitly enable it.

#### Otherwise the switch only works out-of-the-box as a “dumb” switch in unmanaged mode.

The Dell PowerConnect 2824 is a switch that works as unmanaged out of the box. But with the literally push of a button you can enable the web interface.

Based on the information on page in [this official Dell PowerConnect 2824 “Getting Started” guide](https://downloads.dell.com/manuals/all-products/esuprt_ser_stor_net/esuprt_networking/esuprt_net_fxd_prt_swtchs/powerconnect-2824_setup%20guide_en-us.pdf), this is what you need to do is push a button on the front panel:

> “The PowerConnect 2808/16/24/48 has a Mode push button on the front panel. The Mode button changes between Managed and Unmanaged modes, or changes from Secure to Managed modes.”

Page 14 further states:

> “To change between managed and unmanaged modes, press the Mode Button for less than seven seconds.”

And on page 17, the actual IP address of the web interface should be `192.168.2.1` (the mask is `255.255.255.0`).

More details on the various management modes can be found here in [the more comprehensive Dell PowerConnect 2824 user guide](https://dl.dell.com/manuals/all-products/esuprt_ser_stor_net/esuprt_networking/esuprt_net_fxd_prt_swtchs/powerconnect-2824_user%27s%20guide_en-us.pdf?dgc=SM&cid=304571&lid=spr3399384316&linkId=90211109) on page 17:

The device can be run in Managed or Unmanaged mode. By default, the device is in Unmanaged mode. These modes are described below:

> - **Managed Mode** — In this mode:
>
>   - Switch can be managed through the web interface.
>   - Managed Mode LED is ON.
>   - Device uses the saved running configuration (if it exists) or the default configuration.
>
>     The current running configuration is automatically saved to local storage. If the system is switched to unmanaged mode via the Managed Mode button, the system does not load the saved configuration, but it is still maintained in the device’s local storage.
>     – From Managed mode, you can move to Unmanaged mode by pressing the Mode button on the device, or you can move to Secure mode using the web interface (see "Entering Secure Mode" on page 62).
>
>   The factory default values, used when the device is in Managed mode, include:
>
>   - IP Address — 192.168.2.1
>   - Netmask — 255.255.255.0
>   - Username — admin
>   - Permission — R/W privilege
>   - DHCP Client — Off
>   - Flow Control — On
>   - STP — Off
> - **Unmanaged Mode** — In this mode:
>
>   - The device does not have an IP address.
>   - STP is disabled.
>   - All ports belong to a single VLAN.
>   - There is no web management interface.
>   - The CLI works in Debug mode only.
>   - Default configuration is used.
>   - Managed Mode LED is OFF.
>   - Return to Managed mode by pressing the Mode button on the device for up to 7 seconds.
> - **Secure Mode** — In this mode:
>
>   - This mode can be entered only from the Web management.
>   - The device retains the existing configuration active, but it prevents users from making configuration changes by removing the IP address of the device so that it becomes inaccessible for configuration.
>   - No web management interface is available, and the CLI works in Debug mode only.
>   - Managed Mode LED is OFF.
>   - Return to Managed mode by pressing the Mode button on the device for up to 7 seconds.
>
>     All modes are maintained throughout power cycles. The Managed Mode LED shows the current mode.